# Display a flag using HTML

Tags: html

Back when I was being taught HTML I remember a tag that displayed a little red flag. I've tried everything I can think of and can't find it anywhere. Was I smoking something that day or is there actually a tag for it?

Comment: `<img src="mylittleredflag.gif">`?

Comment: Um...`<img src="littleredflag.gif" />`?

Comment: Um thanks...
I thought it was actually part of the language, It may have been depreciated though. This wasn't the answer I was looking for btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could in theory do this

```
<span style="color:red;">&#9873;</span>
```

but you'll need a Unicode font that supports the [Black Flag character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2691/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks a heap, not exactly how I remember it but I'm going to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ⚐ but it's not a tag nor it's red.

Comment: Cheers, got beat by a few seconds :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no tag for it. See all [HTML4 tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html).

Comment: Damn, thanks. I looked through similar pages like that and couldn't find it either. Thought it might of been depreciated. I actually don't plan to use it in a web page.